IDE, проблемы выбора и функционала для С++-разработки?
Возникла проблема перехода на новую IDE вследствие несостоятельности текущей и встаёт вопрос "что выбрать?"
Долгое время пользуюсь Code::Blocks, но уже сейчас начались проблемы с разработкой: очень жирная проблема, например, при разработке параллельных программ (нельзя переключиться на другой поток и посмотреть ситуацию там, некорректно выводит кол-во потоков и т.п), многопроцессорных программ (OpenMPI); а также мелочно, например, поздно код подсветит, не выведет подсказку про аргументы функции, объявление переменной или функции или класса не найдет. Вообщем её надо менять!
Смотрел варианты, которые предлагают в интернете, но мнения либо некомпетентные, либо противоречивые. Например, использование Atom (хотя это редактор кода, а не IDE + он уже вымер, так как разработка прекращена) или использование Visual Studio Code (одни говорят о том, что т.к как это редактор хоть и имеет много плагинов, но превращать его в IDE костыльно и неразумно; другая часть его боготворит). Я в этом всём запутался.
P.S Пожалуйста, не предлагайте CLion, ибо

Это проприетарное ПО (при этом даже отсутствует "Community Edition";
Не имею желания привязываться к продуктам компании JetBrains

P.S.S Использовать Visual Studio тоже не могу, т.к надо использовать GNU GCC компилятор. Плюс разработку веду из-под Linux, а там, как я могу судить, проблемы с Visual Studio.

Используйте Visual Studio (не Code). Как вариант, Eclipse CDT, который и опенсурсный и кросплатформенный, но малось отсталый (хотя и не настолько, как  Code::Blocks).

@user7860670 О, спасибо, что написали. Я за этими рассуждениями забыл указать, что мне надо было бы использовать GNU Compiler. Плюс работаю я из-под Линукс, а там Microsoft-овский компилятор, что поставляется вместе с IDE не особо применим (как я могу судить). Сейчас поправлю вопрос, а пока-что в комментариях эта информация.



Не имею желания привязываться к продуктам компании JetBrains


эээ... Ну типа

@ШвеевАлексей "Типа"?

Под линукс из относительно приличных кроме Эклипса еще был KDevelop. Правда, я его в последний раз использовал лет 15 назад - тогда он был очень неплох. А куда развился сейчас - не знаю. Но можете попробовать, вдруг он уже умеет все перечисленное.

QtCreator вполне неплох как IDE - довольно легкий и шустрый, компилятор можно практически любой прикрутить, Да, он не только для Qt.

В большинстве IDE можно использовать разные компиляторы. Например, в VS можно подключить и GCC, и Clang. | Если речь о Linux, то современное стильное молодёжное - Visual Studio Code.

Попробуйте VSC. Весь вопрос в том, какие плагины на него ставить (мне понравились Clangd и LLDB-DAP вместо стандартного C/C++-плагина).

А вы уверены, что IDE в самом деле нужна? Я, например, пробовал eclipse, но вернулся к просто emacs, make, gdb  и нескольким nix* утилитам

@avp Ну... В таком случае надо подумать. Но склоняюсь, что IDE предпочтительнее. А что еще за "несколько nix* утилит", если не секрет?

@Yulia, самые обычные grep, find, awk, sed ... (для поиска и вытаскивания текстовых данных) и ar, nm, objdump и т.п. для просмотра библиотек, таблиц символов и дизасемблирования. Другими словами вы просто сами используете весь *nix так как вы умеете, а не так, как вам его подсовывают авторы IDE

Могу сказать одно, если вы владеете слепой печатью, то используйте neovim. Плагинов куча, cmake, все кроссплатформенное. Да и чтобы его освоить, на начальном этапе достаточно пройти :Tutor, очень удобно и практично. С vscode visual studio, лучше не связываться, вы свяжите себе руки плагинами, и intelli sense.

@evo Спасибо, но разве intellisense - это плохо? Сейчас писать код без автодополнения же слишком старомодно?

@Yulia, с таким успехом можно сказать что писать код самому руками это старомодно, ведь есть AI который тоже умеет это делать. Имеется ввиду авто завершение кода. Вот проблема.
